# Is it possible to sort an ArrayList of integers using comparable or comparator?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, comparator

I am trying to sort an ArrayList using comparable interface. 
How do I sort ArrayList in descending or ascending order?

Answer (score 2):

You're able to sort an ArrayList if the elements implement Comparable. For example, Integers can be sorted with sort():

```
Collections.sort(arrayList)
```

> Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface can be
> sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort).
>
> from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html